# programmatically change data on Exchange Server

Tags: c#, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I would like to know what is the possibilities to programmatically change data on Exchange Server?

with Exchange Web Service (EWS) can I (change means add/edit/delete):

- change data on Exchange Server for other users?
- change Global Address List?

if not, how I can do that programmatically?

we have a system that we need to make it communicate with Exchange Server to do different tasks, related to calendar, email, GAL

what is the best practice and approach I should think about?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont't know what about GAL, but surely You can manage users calendars(adding meeting,s adding taksks, ...) and emails(reading, sending etc.).

To manage other user accounts You have to enable impersonation.

Some time ago I wrote two posts on my blog how to impersonate Exchange Service Binding and how to add an appointment to any users calendar in Exchange. I won't paste the code here because it makes no sense, just here You have links if You're interested:

[Impersonation](http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2010/09/30/exchange-tutorial-part-1-impresonated-exchange-service-binding/)

[Creating appointment](http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2010/10/19/exchange-tutorial-part-2-%E2%80%93-creating-appointment/)

But now it's easier way to achieve the same results as above, but with less lines of code thanks to [Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). So, if You want to enable communication with excahnge You should read more about this API and see if it suits You and Your demands.

Comment: Thank I know that, I made something like your example, I meant can I use some kind of an admin account user to modify someone's else calendar without needing his user-name and password?

Comment: Yes, see "Impersonation" link in my post.